# Split a string by regex in PHP same way as in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, regex, laravel

I am trying to split a string by a **regex** the same way as **javascript**.

So javascript split() will produce the following result:

```
myString = '&&Joe Doe&& should be here with &&Annie Franklin&&, right?';
myParts = myString.split(/&&(.*?)&&/);

//myParts[0] = 'Joe Doe'
//myParts[1] = ' should be here with '
//myParts[2] = 'Annie Franklin'
//myParts[3] = ', right?'
```

Now, good folk, is there any way I can achieve this using **PHP 7**?

Note that the example string from above is a comment in my database, and I'm trying to display it in a Laravel Blade page without executing any HTML markup that is within the comment itself, yet I want to wrap the **$$Firstname Lastname&&** tag with an `<a></a>` html tag.

Comment: If you google "php split a string by a regex" the answer you want is literally the first result...

Comment: what research have you done? What have you tried? A simple google search using terms in your title returns lots of results https://www.google.com/search?q=php+split+string+regex Basic research is expected before asking questions

Comment: I did try all the things I could find, apparently, I missed the right flags for the preg_split function

Comment: It should be `$result = preg_split('/&&(.*?)&&/', $myString, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);` but perhaps just splitting with `&&` is enough as is shown below.

Comment: I believe  I couldn't come up with a solution because I was using this regex: /\&\&[\p{L}\p{N}]+(?:\s+[\p{L}\p{N}]+)*\&\&/,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$myString = '&&Joe Doe&& should be here with &&Annie Franklin&&, right?';
$result = preg_split('/&&/', $myString, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($result);
```

---

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Joe Doe
    [1] =>  should be here with 
    [2] => Annie Franklin
    [3] => , right?
)
```

[PHP Demo](https://ideone.com/WtBJhN)

Comment: This is EXACLY what I wanted! Thank you very much!

Comment: Wasn't me, but really...why are you complicating it making the delimiter zero  width just because you want to use the flag for capturing the delimiter itself?

Comment: I just grabbed the question's regex  and converted in `preg_split`, I'll update my answer, tks for pointing that.

Comment: I will do exactly that, but you can't accept an answer in the first 15 minutes or so, thanks!

Comment: @PedroLobito In the method that I described in the question, the javascript way, I know for sure that if **myParts[n]** is a matched expression( a "tag", by case), **myParts[n+1]** will be non-tag. While using the answer you provided this is not applicable, can you point a way to do so?

Comment: @PedroLobito I achieved the desired result by using the regex you've provided initially(same as I used in js).

Comment: If thats the case then @PedroLobito I have posted this answer before yours, you edited after your downvote, isnt that biased ;) #justAthouught

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$myString = '&&Joe Doe&& should be here with &&Annie Franklin&&, right?';
$pattern = '/&&(.*?)&&/';
$result = preg_split($pattern, $myString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below:

```
 $keywords = preg_split("/&&/", "&&Joe Doe&& should be here with &&Annie Franklin&&, right?");
 print_r($keywords);
```

[image]

Comment: @PedroLobito I have posted this answer before yours, you edited after your downvote, isnt that biased ;) #justAthouught